# java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.view.Surface.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am developing an application, and one strange thing is if I repeated run-ins an activity of my app which was developing by OpenGL ES, my app occasionally raise a crash, here is the crash stack as below, any idea for my this crash?

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.view.Surface.finalize() timedout after 10 seconds
    at android.view.Surface.nativeRelease(Native Method)
    at android.view.Surface.release(Surface.java:182)
    at android.view.Surface.finalize(Surface.java:158)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:190)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:173)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: This crash only appera on nubia Z11 mini, maybe it's a device problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using Instant run disable it, some times this will raise this problem.

Explanation: TimeoutException occur where it is waiting for some process but non of the process responded, look in to the code and look in to the Android Monitor where the crash occur during development.

Other scenarios updates studio and java